# react-native-webview doesn't open new tab in external browser

Tags: react-native, webview, expo, react-native-webview

I have added a website (https://www.roomvo.com/my/vekoal/rooms/615c4480f40c40c4ba624a8c2f2f3f23) inside react-native-webview that it is developed with Next.js. On this website are two buttons on the right menu drawer that shares on Facebook and Whatsapp by opening new tabs, but non of them is working inside react-native-webview. I hate tried to add some props that I think will help me but no success. Can anyone help me with this, please?

**To Reproduce:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'; 

const HomeScreen = props => { 
  return (
    <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://www.roomvo.com/my/vekoal/rooms/615c4480f40c40c4ba624a8c2f2f3f23' }} />
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

**Expected behavior:**
I expect to open a new tab external on phone default browser.

**Environment:**

```
OS: Android
OS version: 9.0
Expo version: 4.1.0
Expo SDK version: 40.0.0
react-native version: 0.63
react-native-webview version: 11.0.0
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to your question?

Comment: No, I haven't. I created a new button that share a screenshot of the view

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for?

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'; 
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
const HomeScreen = props => { 
    const handleWebViewNavigationStateChange = (
        newNavState
      ) => {
        const {url} = newNavState;
          //check if facebook or whatever you want
          if(url.includes('facebook')){
            Linking.openURL(url);
            return false;
          }

      };
  return (
    <WebView 
        onNavigationStateChange={handleWebViewNavigationStateChange}
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.roomvo.com/my/vekoal/rooms/615c4480f40c40c4ba624a8c2f2f3f23' }} 
        />
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```